# failed in convergence using adabelif optimizer

Tags: python, optimization, convergence

using adabelif optimizer for training the vit model but failed to converge in finetuning task
i used optax.adabelif() optimizer ,in this change learing rate from 0.0001 to 0.1  but failed
also change the other parameters but dont get converge value in here the graph it show [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2WAVu.png)

here is piece of code where go to train.py file and change the optimzer from sgd to adabelif but in adabeilf it dont converge

```
  total_steps = config.total_steps

  lr_fn = utils.create_learning_rate_schedule(total_steps, config.base_lr,
                                              config.decay_type,
                                              config.warmup_steps)
  tx = optax.chain(
      optax.clip_by_global_norm(config.grad_norm_clip),
      optax.adabelief(
          learning_rate=0.00001 ,
          b1=0.9,
          b2=0.999,
          weight_decay=0.0,  
          eps=1e-8, 
          eps_root=1e-16
          ),
    #   optax.sgd(
    #       learning_rate=lr_fn,
    #       momentum=0.9,
    #       accumulator_dtype='bfloat16',
    #       nesterov=True,
    #   ),
  )
```

i also do changing in finetunning part in code here is the piece of code

```
# 100 Steps take approximately 15 minutes in the TPU runtime.
total_steps = 100
warmup_steps = 5
decay_type = 'cosine'
grad_norm_clip = 0.25  
# This controls in how many forward passes the batch is split. 8 works well with a TPU runtime that has 8 devices. 64 should work on a GPU. You can of course
# also adjust the batch_size above, but that would require you to adjust the learning rate accordingly.
accum_steps = 8
base_lr = 0.03
```

If any could tell me which side I'm doing incorrectly. What I need to do to get convergence, that'd be awesome.